# Como imprimir variable en JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Quisiera imprimir el alert(Mensaje) para que apareciera en la pagina en vez de ser una alerta pero no se como hacerlo. Alguien me podria ayudar?

```
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1>Utilizando una API de Warframe en React</h1>
          <p>Aca se pueden ver las ultimas 5 noticias de importantes de Warframe</p>
          <button onClick={this.handlerClick}>Imprimir noticias</button>
        </header>
        
      </div>
    );
  }

    handlerClick(){
      function funcionCallback(datos){
        for(var i=0; i<5 ; i++){
          var reliquias = datos.fissures[i];
          var Mensaje = "Reliquias activas: \nPlaneta: " + (reliquias.node) + "\nMision: " + (reliquias.missionType) + "\nEnemigos: " + (reliquias.enemy) + "\nTipo: " + (reliquias.tier)
          alert(Mensaje);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Debes cambiar

```
<button onClick={this.handlerClick}>Imprimir noticias</button>
```

por

```
<button onClick={() => this.handlerClick()}>Imprimir noticias</button>
```

de lo contrario **(creo)** se ejecutara antes de ser renderizado

Comment: Pero eso no afecta a como se imprime la variable Mensaje

Comment: ya me fije! XD seguramente porque en ningun lugar haces uso de `funcionCallback()` dentro de tu `handlerClick()`

Answer (score 0):

En tu handlerClick() estas declarando la función funcionCallback(), la cual en lo que muestras no esta siendo ejecutada, para ejecutarla en el handlerClick() luego de declarar funcionCallback(), deberías llamarla, funcionCallback(params), ejemplo:

```
handlerClick(){
      function funcionCallback(datos){
        for(var i=0; i<5 ; i++){
          var reliquias = datos.fissures[i];
          var Mensaje = "Reliquias activas: \nPlaneta: " + (reliquias.node) + "\nMision: " + (reliquias.missionType) + "\nEnemigos: " + (reliquias.enemy) + "\nTipo: " + (reliquias.tier)
          alert(Mensaje);
        } 

       funcionCallback(this.state.datos);
}
```

Espero sea de ayuda, e intenta que esas funciones queden no encapsuladas en otra función, ojala sean funciones hermanas, para que así puedas reutilizarlas.

Answer (score 0):

No es necesario crear la función `funcionCallback(datos)` dentro de `handlerClick()`, con hacerlo a nivel de ésta última bastaría.

Si necesitas pasarle argumentos tienes que invocarla con `onClick={() => this.handlerClick(x)}`, aunque depende cómo quieras hacerlo ya que a veces tiene más sentido utilizar `hooks` externos a la función (por ejemplo en formularios de login, que los datos se obtienen de diferentes sitios).